# Ionic nav-bar: Title is not centered on Android Device

Tags: ionic-framework

Im very new to Ionic but i already like it. I wanted to use the `nav-bar`so i implemented the following index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

    <!-- Ionic -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- myApp -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/general.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/factory.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>

</html>
```

In my app.js i configure the pathing:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('index', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
    }).state('prints', {
        url: '/prints',
        templateUrl: 'views/photo_prints.html'
    }).state('box', {
        url: '/box',
        templateUrl: 'views/photo_box.html'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
});
```

And one example page:

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content ng-controller="HomeController">
        <a href="#/prints">Prints</a></br></br>
        <a href="#/box">Box</a></br></br>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

When i test everything in my google chrome browser on my pc everything looks like it should. The title is centered.

When i now test it on my android device (which should also use google chrome as i know), i get the following result:

[image]

As you can see the Title is not centered. How can i fix that?
Unfortunately i have no other device to test it.

Comment: it's not a bug, in android essentially title align left

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try add the `align-title="center"` attribute in your ion-nav-bar

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive" align-title="center">
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

Comment: I think the correct way to achieve this is by using the $ionConfig to globally override the behaviour and instead use the approach on a special case basis. This way you wont have to use align-title on every view and can abstract it away.

Comment: I tried this , But could not get it to work . Please Help .

Comment: @32teeths try the answer below which I think is the correct way .

Answer (score 45):

By design Android titles are aligned to the left. I believe the correct way to change this behaviour is by using the $ionicConfigProvider in your angular **.config** method for your main angular module. 
This provider has a property navBar.alignTitle(value) where "value" can be platform(default), left, right or center. This is described in the docs [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/)

For example

```
var myApp = angular.module('reallyCoolApp', ['ionic']);

myApp.config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {

  // note that you can also chain configs
  $ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle('center');
});
```

This In my opinion is the correct way to override this behaviour.

Comment: This IS the correct way! It should be the accepted answer IMO.

Comment: You can now do something like $ionicConfigProvider.platfrom.android.navBar.alignTitle('center'); to target only android or $ionicConfigProvider.platfrom.ios.navBar.alignTitle('center'); for ios only. This works for all configs too. See http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/ for a full list.

Answer (score 6):

I think that this is a better solution for images. Add it to app.scss

```
.back-button {
    z-index: 100;
}
ion-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a fix for **Ionic 2.0.x**

Add the following style to your **.scss** file (I placed it in app.scss)

```
//  Centering title
// --------------------------------------------------
// a fix for centering the title on all the platforms

ion-header {
  .button-md {
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  .toolbar-title {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

After that add the following markup to your page

```
<ion-header>
  <!-- use ion-toolbar for a normal toolbar and ion-navbar for navigation -->
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons left>
      <!-- left aligned content here -->
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-title>
      Your title or image
    </ion-title>

    <ion-buttons right>
      <!-- left aligned content here -->
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: Unfortunately long titles get truncated from both left and right on small screens (mobile phones).

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the above answer, you can simply use `$ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle('center');` and override the centering behavior of all your view titles. OR, if you need to change the position of your view title on other views, then you can simply make use of `center` HTML tag around the title. You can see the demo here [Ionic Title](http://technotip.com/4784/positioning-the-title-ionic-apps/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<ion-view>
<ion-nav-title class="title">Login
</ion-nav-title>
<ion-content>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: you should add some context to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<ion-header >
 <div align="center">
  <ion-navbar>
     <ion-title primary>Tittle</ion-title>
   </ion-navbar>
 </div>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i am changed css and redefine the css like this

```
.bar.bar-header .button+.title {
text-align: center !important;
left: 35px;
line-height: 46px;
}
```

its work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many of the solutions listed here and still had the following 2 issues with native Android builds:

1. The title text either getting shifted off the left side of the screen or just plain not appearing at all
2. The title text not being vertically centered in the nav bar

The following CSS resolved both of these issues for me:

```
.platform-android .bar .title {
    line-height: 52px !important;  // vertically centers title on native Android builds
}

.bar .title {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px !important;
    right: 0px !important;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center !important;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```