# Ionic 4 ion-title in toolbar is not centered on android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am wondering if this a common problem. My `ion-title` is not centered in the toolbar on android.

I googled it but I couldn't find anything for ionic 4, what I did found was a pretty good solution in ionic 3.

here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30021395/4983589

I am wondering if somebody know how to do this in ionic4?

Here an image how it looks on android:

[image]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Ionic v4** keeps **toolbar title** on left for android devices and on center for IOS devices.

To use a particular behavior you can use `mode="md|ios"`. md is for android and ios for IOS devices.

Since you want to make the title on center, you can use `mode="ios"` which will make the toolbar title to be on center for both android and ios devices.

This is my header:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar mode="ios">
        <ion-title>
            Add New Rest
        </ion-title>
        <ion-icon slot="end" name="analytics"></ion-icon>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-buttons slot="start">
                <ion-back-button defaultHref="home"></ion-back-button>
            </ion-buttons>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Have a look at the screenshot below
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thats because you are using mode='ios' this is only happening on android.

Comment: @Sireini added some explanation to my answer, have a look.

Comment: Yes but it also uses the ios icons when you use mode="ios"?

Comment: @Sireini please have a look at the screenshots now, you can see different icons for ios and android.

Comment: but title in android is cutting off now

Comment: `mode="ios"` worked flawlessly. I've been banging my head since two days :/

Comment: Awesome! This is what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have tested the followings on my android and the title is centered with other buttons such as back button, etc.

Not too sure if it works on iOS devices
Hopefully this helps:

```
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title style="width: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0; height: 0;">
        Title
    </ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Comment: What if there is back button?

Answer (score 2):

Adding mode="ios" does work. To simplify you can add mode="ios" to the main HTML tag in the index.html and this will be applied to the entire app so you don't have to add this to each individual HTML page.

Comment: Can you add explanation/reference to how this solves the problem in a better way than the accepted answer?

Comment: **This is an addition to the accepted answer. You can add mode="ios" to each page you want to style individuality but this could involve a lot of repeated code depending on how large of a project you have. If you add this to the main HTML tag in the index.html you only have enter this code once and it will be applied to the entire project and save you from having to add this to each page.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" mode="ios">

Comment: This will impact all the components in the entire app.. and not just the ion-toolbar.. everything will take up 'ios' look and feel..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep android mode,
you can do the following in your global .scss file:

```scss
ion-title {
  &.md {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

This way on the iOS mode title is already centered, you will only be changing the title alignment on the android